# Get request is correctly resolving my controller, but not invoking the correct (or any) action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

I have a web project with two models - `IndicatorModel` and `GranteeModel`.  I also have corresponding ApiControllers for each - `IndicatorsController`, and `GranteesController`.  I'm planning on using this setup for a data API alongside my actual web project, so I've created a new Area in my project named simply "Api".  In my `ApiAreaRegistration` class, I'm registering routes for these controllers like this:

```
context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "ApiDefault",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Basically, a request to `http://myapp/api/indicators/123` should go to the Indicators controller, and it should specifically be handled by an action method that accepts an integer parameter.  My controller class is setup as follows, and it works perfectly:

```
public class IndicatorsController : ApiController
{
    // get: /api/indicators/{id}
    public IndicatorModel Get(int id)
    {
        Indicator indicator = ...// find indicator by id
        if (indicator == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return new IndicatorModel(indicator);
    }
}
```

My `GranteesController` class is setup identically:

```
public class GranteesController : ApiController
{
    // get: /api/grantees/{id}
    public GranteeModel Get(int granteeId)
    {
        Grantee grantee = ... // find grantee by Id
        if (grantee == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return new GranteeModel(grantee);
    }
}
```

Now the problem - if I try a request to `http://myapp/api/grantees/123`, I get a 404 and I'm 100% positive that the 404 is **not** coming from my Get method.  For one, I've tried debugging and logging within that method, and the method is never actually hit.  Also, the actual output (json) to the request looks like this:

```
{ 
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://myapp/api/grantees/25'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Grantees' that matches the request."
}
```

Also, the output to my TraceWriter log looks like this:

```
;;http://myapp/api/grantees/10
DefaultHttpControllerSelector;SelectController;Route='controller:grantees,id:10'
DefaultHttpControllerSelector;SelectController;Grantees
HttpControllerDescriptor;CreateController;
DefaultHttpControllerActivator;Create;
DefaultHttpControllerActivator;Create;MyApp.Areas.Api.Controllers.GranteesController
HttpControllerDescriptor;CreateController;MyApp.Areas.Api.Controllers.GranteesController
GranteesController;ExecuteAsync;
ApiControllerActionSelector;SelectAction;
DefaultContentNegotiator;Negotiate;Type='HttpError', formatters=[JsonMediaTypeFormatterTracer...
```

So my request is getting routed correctly - the correct controller is selected, and the Id property is set correctly (10).  However, the `ApiControllerActionSelector` isn't finding a method on the controller which matches.  I've also tried adding in the `[HttpGet]` attribute to my Get methods, with no success.

Does anyone have any ideas of what might be happening here?  I cannot for the life of me figure out why the action selector isn't finding the correct action.

Comment: FYI - this is ASP.NET Web API, which shipped with MVC 4.

Comment: Oh, yup - sorry, should have included that.  I'm using version 4.0.20710.0 for all the WebApi stuff, which is the most up-to-date stable version as far as I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter name on GranteesController's action need to be modified from 'granteeId' to 'id':

public GranteeModel Get(int **id**)

Comment: This is one thing to fix, however, this mistake shouldn't prevent the action from being called, unless the API's controller works differently. In a normal controller, the ID simply wont get mapped and the result will be a binding error, not a 404. However, like I said, WebAPI controllers MIGHT work differently in that regard, so start by fixing this and let us know if everything is fine :)

Comment: Wow, this is embarassing :)  Kiran is 100% correct - I changed the parameter name in my Get method, and it worked like a charm.  I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you!